# JUnit5: How to assert several properties of an object with a single assert call?

Tags: java, junit, junit5, hamcrest, assertj

I want to assert several properties of an object with a single assert call.

With JUnit 4 and Hamcrest I would have written something like this:

```
assertThat(product, allOf(
        hasProperty("name", is("Coat")),
        hasProperty("available", is(true)),
        hasProperty("amount", is(12)),
        hasProperty("price", is(new BigDecimal("88.0")))
));
```

**Q:** How to assert several properties in a single assert call using JUnit 5 and AssertJ? Or, alternatively, what is the best way of doing that in JUnit 5 universe.

**Note:** I can of course create an object with all needed properties and perform

```
assertThat(actualProduct, is(expectedProduct))
```

but that is not the point.

Comment: This is still possible using [JUnit 5 and Hamcrest](https://www.petrikainulainen.net/programming/testing/junit-5-tutorial-writing-assertions-with-hamcrest/) but I also prefer the way David mentioned

Answer (score 28, accepted):

With AssertJ, another option would be to use [`returns`](https://www.javadoc.io/doc/org.assertj/assertj-core/latest/org/assertj/core/api/AbstractObjectAssert.html#returns(T,java.util.function.Function)):

```
import static org.assertj.core.api.Assertions.from;

assertThat(product)
    .returns("Coat", from(Product::getName))
    .returns(true, from(Product::getAvailable))
     //
     // or without 'from()'
     //
    .returns(12, Product::getAmount)
    .returns(new BigDecimal("88.0"), Product::getPrice);
```

A bit more verbose but I find it easier to read compared to `extracting`/`contains`.

Note that [`from`](https://www.javadoc.io/doc/org.assertj/assertj-core/latest/org/assertj/core/api/Assertions.html#from(java.util.function.Function)) is just an optional syntax sugar to improve readability.

---

Since 3.22.0, [`doesNotReturn`](https://www.javadoc.io/doc/org.assertj/assertj-core/latest/org/assertj/core/api/AbstractObjectAssert.html#doesNotReturn(T,java.util.function.Function)) is also available. This can be useful for non-null fields where the expected value is not known in advance.

```
assertThat(product)
    .returns("Coat", from(Product::getName))
    .returns(true, from(Product::getAvailable))
    .doesNotReturn(42, from(Product::getAmount))
    .doesNotReturn(null, from(Product::getPrice));
```

Comment: Very interesting alternative (+1).  I didn't know that. IHMO, for objects with many properties to assert, it makes sense. For other cases, probably less.  Note that `from` is optional. It is a reading marker.

Comment: @Stefano Cordio Thanks for this suggestion. This is a great way to express assertions. I updated your sample as it wasn't compiling with the commas (and also to include the suggestion by @davidxxx that `from()` is optional).

Answer (score 19):

With AssertJ the closest is :

```
assertThat(product).extracting("name", "available", "amount", "price")
                   .containsExactly("Coat", true, 12, new BigDecimal("88.0"));
```

But I don't like to reference field names with `String`s because their validity as field names are checked only at the runtime (known issue of reflection) and that these `String`s may also be incorrectly updated during refactoring operations that we perform from the IDE.

While a little more verbose, I prefer that :

```
assertThat(product).extracting(Product::getName, Product::getAvailable, 
                               Product::getAmount, Product::getPrice)
                   .containsExactly("Coat", true, 12, new BigDecimal("88.0"));
```

The advantage of AssertJ over Hamcrest that you quote is that that is really fluent : so in most of cases, you need a single import : `import org.assertj.core.api.Assertions;` and for collection assertions, sometimes that : `org.assertj.core.groups.Tuple;`

Here JUnit 5 or 4; it doesn't really matter since you will only use JUnit as a test runner for a very simple case  and leave AssertJ to perform the assertions.

> Or, alternatively, what is the best way of doing that in JUnit 5
>   universe.

JUnit 5 (as the 4th version) doesn't provide features for flexible and fluent assertions. So doing it with the best way of JUnit 5 is bound to produce much more boiler plate code : as many assertions as fields to assert or overriding `equals()/hashCode()` override that you want to avoid for fair reasons.

Answer (score 7):

You could use `Assertions.assertAll`:

```
assertAll("product",
   () -> assertEquals("Coat", product.getName()),
   () -> assertTrue(product.isAvaikable())
);
```

assertAll can take as many individual asserts as you like. Here’s the link to the section in the user guide: https://junit.org/junit5/docs/current/user-guide/#writing-tests-assertions

Comment: That is right. But that is really very verbose too.