# Testing object method return values

Tags: java, junit, assertj

I have an object under test and want to verify it was configured correctly by testing the return values of methods. Is there a way to do this without creating one test per method?

I'm imagining something like:

```
assertThat(obj).fieldIs(Obj::methodA, "value1").fieldIs(Obj::methodB, "value1");
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [JUnit5: How to assert several properties of an object with a single assert call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57476351/junit5-how-to-assert-several-properties-of-an-object-with-a-single-assert-call)

Answer (score 1):

You can make a big test method that tests all fields of the object are as they should be, you aren't limited to one `assertSomething()` per method.
Example:

```java
@Test
public void testFields() {
    Object someObj = theObjInstance;
    assertEquals("value1", someObj.methodA());
    assertEquals("value2", someObj.methodB());
    // ...
}
```